# Continue Mega download

Tags: google-chrome, download, mega

I was downloading a file from mega but the browser(Chrome) freezed.
As I was not using an account so I cannot continue downloading or from there.
Is there any way I could do the same or do I have to download again. The file is pretty big so I was thinking maybe there was another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you weren't logged in & your session was broken by the crash, the chances of you re-discovering it are extremely slim. Best you can hope is that the partially-downloaded file in the browser has a resume button & it manages to auto-negotiate.

The general rule for any large file download is, 'Don't use a browser, use a downloader'.
This is less important these days than it used to be, because ISPs don't cache files en-route as much as they used to, but it still affords some kind of protection for such as this situation.

For Mega specifically…

1. Get an account. That will save you all this trouble.
   Basic is free. If you use them a lot, pay for their services, same as any other service you need.
2. Use their own downloader [see 1 above].